# Iterate through my django model to generate weather info for each city

Tags: python, django, api, restful-url

How do I iterate through my django model to be able to generate the weather info for each city? The db is showing info for the first city name only

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from pytz import timezone

# Create your models here.
class city(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class weather(models.Model):
    City=models.ForeignKey(city, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    timezone=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    temperature=models.FloatField()
    humidity=models.FloatField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import weather,city

class CitySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=city
        fields='__all__'

class WeatherSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=weather
        fields='__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from .models import weather,city
from .serializers import WeatherSerializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def weatherinfo(request):
    Cit=city.objects.all()
    geolocator=Nominatim(user_agent="XXXXXXXX")
    key= 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
    for obj in Cit:
        #cit=city.objects.get(city,id=obj)
        location=geolocator.geocode(obj)
        coordinates=(location.latitude,location.longitude)
        lat=coordinates[0]
        long=coordinates[1]
        url='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={}&lon= 
        {}&appid={}'.format(lat,long,key)
        city_weather=requests.get(url).json()

        weather_data=weather.objects.create(
        City=obj,
        country=city_weather['sys']['country'],
        timezone=city_weather['timezone'],
        temperature=city_weather["main"]["temp_max"], 
        humidity=city_weather["main"]["humidity"],
        status=city_weather["weather"][0]["description"],
        )

        serializer=WeatherSerializers(weather_data, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note: The output of the weather info doesn't contain info for all of the city names after iteration. It is only returning info for the first city name in the database.

Comment: i think weather_data from loop is the last created object. i think you need to pass to serializer weather.objects.filter(city__in=Cit) and many=True

Comment: I still do not understand. Do you mean I should override weather_data in the serializer with  weather.objects.filter(city__in=Cit)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the first city and weather data in your for-loop. After returning anything, the loop is finish.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def weatherinfo(request):
    # ... your code
    for obj in Cit:
        # ... your code
        serializer=WeatherSerializers(weather_data, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)  # <- this will break/stop the for loop
```

Instead you should write something like (please consider this only as a draft; it may not be working as copy'n'paste)

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def weatherinfo(request):
    # ... your code
    weather_data_results = []
    for obj in Cit:
        # ... your code
        serializer=WeatherSerializers(weather_data, many=False)
        weather_data_results.append(serializer.data)
    return Response(weather_data_results)
```